# Хранение и обновление табличных данных в Postgresql

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, проектирование

Для моего приложения, в базе нужно хранить табличные данные, с точной последовательностью и возможностью редактировать поля.
Вот пример таблицы на клиенте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас я думаю так:

Сущность строка row:

 - row_position (хранит номер строки на которой она записана)

 - year - год

 - rank - разряд, значение из справочника

Сущность колонка col - это значения под колонками Группа А, Группа В..

 - col_position (хранит номер колонки на которой она записана)

 - col_content (json с разными предметами)

Мой вопрос о том, как хранить таблицы в базе, с возможность редактирования. Так же на колонки из групп могут ссылаться другие сущности. И что бы при редактировании колонок ничего не сломалось, а сущности так же могли ссылаться на колонки.

Comment: Хранить как обычно - в 3НФ, а для вывода на клиента использовать `crosstab`. "Как ничего не сломать" - вопрос философский. Единственный метод, дающий 100% гарантию "не сломать" - ничего не делать.

Comment: @Dmitry То есть хранить номер колонки и строки отдельно?  
| col_n | row_n | id |

Comment: То, что у вас в колонках, должно храниться в строках. Есть такое понятие - pivot table ([Сводная таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)). Вот у вас задача явно такая же, в постгресе для этого есть функция `crosstab`.

Comment: @Dmitry как можно с вами связаться? Я в базах совсем ноль.
А эту таску срочно нужно выполнить.

Comment: Не надо со мной связываться, я вас плохому научу. Если вас устроит объяснение в общих чертах - могу ответ написать. Я последний раз работал с постгресом 10 лет назад, и под рукой у меня его нет, а с node.js не работал вообще.

Comment: @Dmitry если конкретно, то мне нужно просто спроектировать базу. Ничего писать не нужно) тем более на ноде.

Comment: Тогда удалите тег `node.js`, он тут ни к чему.

Answer (score 0):

Я не понял, как называется ваша основная сущность, ну пусть это будет какой-то результат. Тогда таблицы вам нужны следующие:

Главная сущность с результатом:

```
result
--------
year
rank_id
group_id
content
```

Разряды:

```
rank
---------
rank_id
rank_name
seq        <-- для сортировки
```

Группы:

```
group
---------
group_id
group_name
seq        <-- для сортировки
```

Сгенерировать требуемый отчет можно запросом:

```
select * 
  from crosstab('select res.year, r.rank_name, g.group_name, res.content
                   from result res
                        join rank r on r.rank_id = res.rank_id
                        join group g on g.group_id = res.group_id
                  order by res.year, r.seq',
                'select group_name from group order by seq')
  AS ct(year text, rank_name text, group1 text, group2 text, group3 text, ...) 
  -- количество групп в объявлении будет зависеть от того, что возвращает второй запрос
```

Функция `crosstab` по умолчанию не установлена, ее надо доустанавливать отдельно (но это не сложно). [Пример в документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html) (ваш случай в п. F.35.1.4.). Там,  помнится, были еще какие-то особенности работы у этой функции, но я за давностью лет забыл.